# Intergerate WPF application module into Window Forms based application

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have create a wpf application which has one mainwindow.xaml and two user controls usercontrol.xaml and usercontrol2.xaml.

Now i want this WPF application to be run under window form platform. Is this possible by any means ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) control on your form.

There is a good tutorial on the subject [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms).